# Pay by invoice - how to send and handle due date

Tags: expresso-store

As far as I can gather, i should use the payment type Manual for this purpose.

I have created an invoice template in EE, but I have two questions

1) Is there some obvious way of sending it to the customer?

2) How can i handle the due date? It has to be set for X weeks after the date the invoice is actually sent

Is this something I can do with Store, or will I have to look elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built into Store that allows you to limit access to products to certain members. Having said that there are a few ways you can get around this. A while back I wrote a blog post about using [Simple Commerce for creating invoices](http://iamjustinlong.com/blog/single/simple_commerce_simple_invoicing_software/). While doing this with Store will be a bit different you might be able to apply some of the template logic or ideas into your setup.

1.) You will need to use an add-on to send the email to the client. You can use something like MX Notify or PostMaster to send the email when you submit the order (I would probably combine this with a status parameter so you can edit/draft the invoice before it is sent).

2.) You would again need to use an add-on to have a due date automatically sent. Personally I set the due dates manually but something like [AutoExpire](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/auto-expire) should do the trick, just remember to allow expired entries in your channel entries tags on the front-end.

All that said, there is not an out of the box solution that will allow you to do something like this, but it very doable.

**EDIT**

If you are still using Store v1 oppose to the newly released Store v2 you might be able to use [Store: Quotations](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-quotations) for your needs. I have never used it personally so I am not sure of all of it's features.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could set up the due date - use a custom order field. Store provides up to 9 custom text fields per order. You would need to generate a hidden field during checkout which fills one of these fields with the date you need (either using javascript or an add-on which can generate dates for you).

This would make it very easy to display in the order confirmation email etc.

If you use the manual payment gateway then you can use the order confirmation email to send to your customer, or create an additional status and configure an email to be sent when you change the order to that status.

Comment: Can i send a different order confirmation email depending the payment type used?

Comment: No, but you can use conditionals to display different text in a single email. e.g. `{if payment_method == "paypal"}extra text{/if}`